# Image in static couldnt be found without using CSS under Django frame

Tags: django

I want to input an image in the .html so I put the image in the static files and I don't want to apply CSS. But it says it can't find that pic I wanna use.
In the .html file, I wrote like this

```
<img src="images/background.jpg alt="It is an img">
```

So, can anybody tell me what to do or anything I should change in other files like settings.py?

[image]

My files context is what the image shows.

Answer (score 0):

Please add some code for better understanding of your question, and you can add image directly in your question without sharing external links.

For static file you can use,

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'your image location' %}" alt=image>

# in your case location is 'lemonade/images/background.jpg'
```

Here is the official document,
[Django Static Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/)

Comment: <img src="{% static 'your image location' %}" alt=image>    It doesnt allow to show the image. While I change it into  <img src="{% static "your image location "%}" alt=image > Then it works!

Comment: That is also correct. Sometimes, first " take the second one as the closing tag. To avoid confusion I have used " for outside and ' for inside.